# Replace spaces with sed and regexp grouping not working

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

Somewhy replace empty chars (space, tab, etc.) is not working with sed and regexp grouping:

```
sed -i "s|dir(\s*)=(\s*)'${site_path_source}'|dir$1=$2'${site_path_target}'|g"
```

The whole line does replace a string in a file:

```
sudo find "${config_path}" -type f -exec sed -i "s|dir(\s*)=(\s*)'${site_path_source}'|dir$1=$2'${site_path_target}'|g" {} \;
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT1:
Now using -r to enable extended regular expressions, but still doesn't replace:

```
sudo find "${config_path}" -type f -exec sed -ir "s|dir(\s*)=(\s*)'${site_path_source}'|dir$1=$2'${site_path_target}'|g" {} \;
```

But still doesn't do the replace.

**EDIT2 (WORKING SOLUTION): When using \( \) for grouping, it WORKS:**

```
sudo find "${config_path}" -type f -exec sed -i "s|dir\(\s*\)=\(\s*\)'${site_path_source}'|dir\1=\2'${site_path_target}'|g" {} \;
```

But I don't understand, why the EDIT1 solution with -r extended regular expressions is not working.

**EDIT3 (WORKING SOLUTION2): Using -r to enable extended regular expressions, it WORKS NOW:**

```
sudo find "${config_path}" -type f -exec sed -r -i "s|dir(\s*)=(\s*)'${site_path_source}'|dir$1=$2'${site_path_target}'|g" {} \;
```

## Explanation:

- **Using "sed -ir SUFFIX" is wrong, because -i needs a suffix.**
- **Using "sed -r -i SUFFIX" is GOOD, because -r and -i are used separately, and -i is followed by a suffix.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
sed -i "s|dir(\s*)=(\s*)'${site_path_source}'|dir$1=$2'${site_path_target}'|g"
```

looks for lines containing `d` `i` `r` `(` zero or more whitespace `)` `=` `(` zero or more whitespace `)` `'` etc. If you are trying to use grouping you must either use `\(` `\)` or say `sed -r` to enable extended regular expressions.

Note that `$1` and `$2` are the first two positional parameters; if you want the first and second groups in the matched string you must use `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget, that sed needs the grouping char to be escaped. Will test the fix today.

Comment: Edited the post. But still no luck. Something is still wrong, no replace done.

Comment: When using escaping the grouping characters works. But if I use -r for extended regular expressions it is not working. Strange. Maybe -i -r options can not be used together?

Comment: Your answer was not a perfect solution, but helped me to find the problem with my sed. So accepting your answer as solution.